# inline asm write value to memory

Tags: c++, c, assembly

How can I write this in inline asm? I want to write the value of packet into the memory location of cave in inline asm, how? I can do it with the WriteProcessMemory but I want to get rid of that and replace with asm

```
int SendToClient(BYTE *packet, int Length)
{
    int cave = (int)VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, Length, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE); 

    if (WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (void*)cave, packet, Length, NULL))
    {

    }

    __asm
    {
        //how?
    }
}
```

for example, say I wanted to read from the address senderOffset I would do:

```
int GetSenderID()
{
    int value;

    __asm
    {
        mov eax, senderOffset
        mov value, eax
    }


    return *(int*)value;
}
```

this is doing what  "ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (VOID*)senderOffset, &value, 0) would do, I'm just looking for the same kinda method to "WriteProcessMemory" with inline asm.

Comment: Which compiler and OS are you using?

Comment: Why inline asm ? Why not simply `memcpy((void*)cave, (void*)packet, length*sizeof(BYTE))`

Comment: Are you compiling for 64 bit?  If so, you're out of luck with MSVS, as it doesn't support inline assembly for x86-64.

Comment: 32bit, I'd like to do it with inline asm because That's what I'm trying to learn.

Comment: but ty memcopy does the job

Comment: @Dean - What? memcpy() does not duplicate the functionality of WriteProcessMemory().  memcpy cannot write into another process's memory space.

Comment: I'm inside the memory space already (injected dll)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want to do is essentially rewrite WriteProcessMemory() in inline assembly, forget it, it ain't gonna happen.  WriteProcessMemory() is an OS interface that allows you to change the content of another process's virtual memory space, which you can't do directly from a user-space process no matter what instructions you use.  No amount of assembly, whether inline or in a separate assembly source file, will be able to cast the magic spells required to allow your process, operating within its virtual memory sandbox, from writing into another process's virtual memory sandbox without going through the OS to do so.  While operating within your user-mode program, the MMU is set up to give your process access to its own memory & nothing else.  Even trying to access memory that's not allocated to your process will give you some sort of access violation error (which is called SIGSEGV in Linux-land; I know you're on Windows though).

To access memory in another process's address space, you have to call on the operating system to do so.  Each system has a controlled way of making OS calls that switches the processor from user-mode to kernel-mode.  In x86, these are termed "rings", with the OS operating in the highest-privileged  "ring 0" and user-mode code running in the least-privileged "ring 3".  Drivers operate in the other two rings.  You cannot simply switch the CPU from ring 3 to ring 0; attempting to do so would trigger a privilege violation.  And within ring 3, you cannot change the MMU to allow your process to access (read or write or execute) another process's memory space.

Comment: No I'm just trying to copy the of packet into the memory located at cave. I'm doing this inprocess, not externally like WriteProcessMemory would work

Comment: @Dean - OK, then why would you be using VirtualAllocEx() to allocate memory, and why would you be using WriteProcessMemory() to copy memory within your own process?

Comment: I allocate memory to store the value, I'm trying not to use WriteProcessMemory for this, that's what I'm asking for help with.

Comment: @Dean - If you're within your own process space, then memcpy() should work.  And if memcpy() works, you shouldn't have to write the code in inline assembly.  memcpy() should be fast enough.  You can't get faster than memcpy() in the general case, as most system's memcpy() is highly optimized.  You can only get faster than memcpy(), and only by a little bit, if you're writing wide data (wider than a byte) from one aligned location to another aligned location.